# Debugging the error [Vertica][VJDBC](100172) One or more rows were rejected by the server

Tags: hdfs, sqoop, vertica

I am getting this error when sqooping records from hdfs to db

I have around 350 columns in that table, what's the ideal way to find out what is causing the issue.

```
2021-04-16 01:41:02,160 INFO [IPC Server handler 27 on 34142] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Diagnostics report from attempt_1618264489948_81800_m_000000_0: Error: java.io.IOException: java.sql.SQLException: [Vertica][VJDBC](100172) One or more rows were rejected by the server.
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AsyncSqlRecordWriter.close(AsyncSqlRecordWriter.java:205)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.close(MapTask.java:670)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:793)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:170)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1869)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:164)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [Vertica][VJDBC](100172) One or more rows were rejected by the server.
    at com.vertica.dsi.dataengine.impl.DSIErrorResult.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.vertica.dataengine.VQueryExecutor.registerBatchInsertResults(Unknown Source)
    at com.vertica.dataengine.VQueryExecutor.readCopyDataResponse(Unknown Source)
    at com.vertica.dataengine.VQueryExecutor.handleExecuteResponse(Unknown Source)
    at com.vertica.dataengine.VQueryExecutor.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.vertica.jdbc.common.SPreparedStatement.executeBatch(Unknown Source)
    at com.vertica.jdbc.VerticaJdbc4PreparedStatementImpl.executeBatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AsyncSqlOutputFormat$AsyncSqlExecThread.run(AsyncSqlOutputFormat.java:231)
Caused by: com.vertica.support.exceptions.ErrorException: [Vertica][VJDBC](100172) One or more rows were rejected by the server.
```

Comment: The best way I discovered was: 1) reduce the input you want to load to the smallest set of data that produces the error. 2) export to CSV file instead of loading through JDBC. 3) Use vsql with the command `COPY target_table FROM LOCAL 'target_data.csv' DELIMITER ',' REJECTMAX 50 EXCEPTIONS '/dev/tty';` This way, a manageable number of error messages is directly printed to the screen. (use `'CON'` instead of `'/dev/tty'` if you run vsql on Windows)